# Linear Regression Transformation of Dependent Variable by Natural Log and a Constant

Tags: data-transformation, least-squares, finance

I have a dependent variable (rolling 12 month stock returns) that includes negative values. The returns are right skewed, so for a normal model without negatives, I would take the natural log. However, with the negatives, this is no longer possible. Due to this problem I added a `constant` such that `constant = min(returns) + .01` to the returns and then took the natural log.

I am wondering about the downsides associated with this technique. I am mainly concerned with whether the independent variables are positive or negative and less concerned with having to reverse my transformation (i.e., not as worried about interpretability).

Little more info: I have 15 predictors with little collinearity among the predictors and I am taking snapshots of the data on a monthly basis.

Any recommendations besides `OLS` are also welcome (I did try `glmnet`).

Comment: Please don't do this.  Have you considered computing the returns in terms of *ratios* rather than differences?  The ratios will be positively skewed, but then you could apply the logarithm.  That's the usual procedure because it's meaningful, interpretable, and does not involve the arbitrary introduction of a start value like $0.01$. It usually works, too.

Comment: "*...the downsides about the downsides*" --- I presume you didn't mean to repeat "downsides" there

Answer (score 1):

Major downsides I can think of offhand include:

1. The magnitude of the natural log of "a tiny bit more than zero" is greater than you may think: |ln(100)| = |ln(0.01)|.

This has substantial implications for the distribution you end up examining. I have trouble posting images from my office, but the histogram of natural logs of values from 1:100 looks different from the histogram of natural logs of values from 0.01:1. With values that you transform just to "cross zero" you end up seeing some oddities that disrupt the distribution of your variable of interest and are not really looking at the logged version of your data so much as an arbitrarily different data set.

2. I definitely understand the urge to use a log transformation on right-skewed data, but I try to reserve it for situations where I think that my distribution might actually be lognormal. Asserting a logarithmic relationship in data is a pretty strong statement about how you think the thing you're modeling works, and making that assertion just to reduce skew seems like a bad trade to me. Do you truly suspect that it might be the case that your dependent variable is related to your dependent ones on a logarithmic scale?

---

As for what to do instead, whuber's suggestion in comments to use ratios is a good one. If all you care about is the sign of each value, you could also use a binary indicator for sign (1 = positive, 0 = negative). Other transformations exist for dealing with rightward skew, though those may not suit your needs either. You may also want to look at nonparametric methods for analyzing your data, which do not require Normality (log or otherwise).